# Unity 2D (Null Reference Exception)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game based on design of super crate box: player collides with box and it chooses a random weapon.
The problem is if the shotgun bullet is active while I shoot again using another gun, I get the exception (I will obviously later make the bullet disappears but the problem also occurs even if the bullet disappears).

I need to press the key really fast for it to happen so I assume the exception only happens when the shotgun bullet is active.

Exception scenario:

- player picks up shotgun
- player fire bullet (bullet doesn't disappear for testing purposes)
- player pick up another gun
- while bullet is still active, player presses control again to fire bullet **=> Exception**

The line where the exception occurs is the first instance of this `Transform cameraTransform = player.transform;`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
public class FireGun : MonoBehaviour
{

     //used to hold the guns user is currently holding
     public List Guns = new List();
     //to acceess pickupbx
     public PickupBx pbx;
     //holds the current name weapon user is holding
     private string weaponFireType;
     //this will get the bullet prefab
     public GameObject BulletPrefab;
     public GameObject shotGunBulletPrefab;
     //bullet position on player
     public GameObject bulletPosition;
     public GameObject shotgunBulletPosition;
     //the player
     public GameObject player;
     //this is the bullet that will be instantiated in scene (rpg/machine      gun)
     public GameObject bulletInScene;
     //this is for the shotgun bullet that will be instantiated
     public GameObject ShotgunBulletInScene;
     //used to make shooty shoot once every few seconds
     private bool shootShottyOnce = false;

     void Start()
     {
          pbx = GetComponent();
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
          if (GetComponent().flipX == true)
          {
               bulletPosition.transform.position = new Vector2(-92, 0);
          }
          else if (GetComponent().flipX == false)
          {
               bulletPosition.transform.position = new Vector2(92, 0);
          }
          AddObjectToList(pbx.guns, Guns);
          checkWeaponType();
     }


     //this method will loop through the gameobjects in pbxguns list (first parameter is the guns list in the pickupBx script), (myList is the list in this script)_
     void AddObjectToList(List pbxGunsList, List myList)
     {
          //loop through all gaeobjects in the pbxGunsList list
          foreach (GameObject go in pbxGunsList)
          {
               //if this list in this script doesn't contain the gameObjects      from the other script
               if (!myList.Contains(go))
               {
                    //clear the list to make sure we don't get duplicates and have weapons in one 1 element
                    myList.Clear();
                    //add the gun to our list
                    myList.Add(go);
               }
          }
     }

     //check weapon the player is holding
     void checkWeaponType()
     {
          //loop through the guns and set the string to weapon player is currently holding
          for (int i = 0; i < Guns.Count; i++)
          {
               if (Guns[i].name == "weapons_0(Clone)")
               {
                    weaponFireType = "MachineGun";
               }
               else if (Guns[i].name == "weapons_1(Clone)")
               {
                    weaponFireType = "Shotgun";
               }
               else if (Guns[i].name == "weapons_2(Clone)")
               {
                    weaponFireType = "RPG";
               }
          }
          //check if user pressed key and check that guns is not empty ( reason shotgun is inputed here is because the shotgun will shoot differently to the other guns
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Guns.Count != 0 && weaponFireType != "Shotgun")
          {
               //make a new gameObject which will hold the bullet in the scene it will instantiate a bullet at the position of the bulletPosition empty gameObject.
               bulletInScene = (GameObject)Instantiate(BulletPrefab, bulletPosition.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
               //the transform of the player
               Transform cameraTransform = player.transform;
               //Makes the player the parent of the GameObject currentGun
               bulletInScene.transform.SetParent(cameraTransform, false);
          }
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && weaponFireType == "Shotgun")
          {
               ShotgunBulletInScene = (GameObject)Instantiate(shotGunBulletPrefab, shotgunBulletPosition.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
               //the transform of the player
               Transform cameraTransform = player.transform;
               //Makes the player the parent of the GameObject currentGun
               ShotgunBulletInScene.transform.SetParent(cameraTransform, false);
          }
          foreach (Transform t in transform)
          {
               if (bulletInScene != null)
               {
                    if (t.name.Contains("Bullet1(Clone)"))
                    {
                         transform.Find("Bullet1(Clone)").transform.parent = null;
                         if (GetComponent().flipX == true && weaponFireType == "MachineGun")
                              bulletInScene.GetComponent().AddForce(Vector2.left * 7500);
                         if (GetComponent().flipX == false && weaponFireType == "MachineGun")
                              bulletInScene.GetComponent().AddForce(Vector2.right * 7500);
                         if (GetComponent().flipX == true && weaponFireType == "RPG")
                              bulletInScene.GetComponent().AddForce(Vector2.left * 4500);
                         if (GetComponent().flipX == false && weaponFireType == "RPG")
                              bulletInScene.GetComponent().AddForce(Vector2.right * 4500);
                    }
               }
          }
          foreach (Transform t in transform)
          {
               if(ShotgunBulletInScene != null)
               {
                    if (t.name.Contains("ShotgunBullet1(Clone)"))
                    {
                         Debug.Log("shotty test");
                         if (shootShottyOnce == false)
                         {
                              StartCoroutine(DestroyShottyBullet());
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }

     IEnumerator DestroyShottyBullet()
     {
          shootShottyOnce = true;
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
          Destroy(ShotgunBulletInScene);
          shootShottyOnce = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full content of the exception log.

Comment: Few advises for your code: instead of calling `Transform cameraTransform = player.transform;` each time the user presses a key, register it at `Start()` and save it into a private variable. Also, instead of `if (bulletInScene != null)  { if (t.name.Contains("Bullet1(Clone)")) { //SOMETHING } }`, you can do `if (bulletInScene != null && t.name.Contains("Bullet1(Clone)") { //SOMETHING }`. This way your code will be much more cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Ok thanks for advice guys I'll try indent it better. EDIT Thanks for that made it alot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that `player` is not set. Judging from the code I assume you either have a prefab and you set it in the inspector, or another script is supposed to set it.

Maybe you are using a different prefab for whatever reason when the shotgun bullet is active and you forgot to assign `player` on that prefab.

Or the script supposed to dynamically assign `player` in the `FireGun` MonoBehaviour is still "looking" at the shotgun's bullet's script and not the new gun's.

Comment: Player is set fine, I do have another script, but its just this one I think is problem. This is what error message says  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
FireGun.checkWeaponType () (at Assets/Scripts/FireGun.cs:133)
FireGun.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/FireGun.cs:58)

Comment: Still attempting to fix it using the normal bullet for the shotgun works fine just not the new bullet no idea why.

Comment: Hey guys so I completly modified it not using the foreach loop I found a better solution but still want to know why it didn't work. But I have a question in programming in general if you can't figure out a problem after say 7 hours like today, do you think its ok to try a new solution or should you learn why it doesn't work?

Comment: It is always difficult to guess when you should give up on a solution. If I spend "too much" (nothing accurate) time on a problem I tend to try something different simply because even on something simple, being too focused on it can stuck my reasoning.

I feel like it's a good idea if you can to keep the code (commented for example) and try to come back to it later with your mind cleared and/or more knowledge, then maybe you have more chance to understand why it didn't work.

Comment: Guys I fixed it with this code! I changed this line  if (t.name.Contains ("Bullet1(Clone)")) to  if (t.name.Equals("Bullet1(Clone)")) Now works but no idea why? Contains is case sensitive so the 2 bullets can be seen as different names I don't see how they conflict anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the next comment can't edit above one but HOLY SHIT is this line why?  transform.Find("Bullet1(Clone)").transform.parent = null; the "Find" method looks for the EXACT name but we can't find it?